# possible to do upsert in hive acid enabled orc table

Tags: hive

After enable the acid support on hive. I can insert/update/delete row from hive table (ORC file based table), wondering is that possible to do upsert? because when user provide data, they don't specify it's insert or update, and if we need to delete before insert for every row to simulate an upsert, it might be very slow but not sure about that performance yet, our update/insert rate is low, less than 5%. For us, latency is not important, but throughput certainly matters. and if hive currently don't support upsert, is there any plan to support it? thanks

Answer (score 2):

The work is in progress: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-10924
Probably the throughput will be limited in ACID mode.

Currently you can simulate upsert not in ACID mode using full join and do full partition/table rewrite. Latency is rather big, throughput is virtually unlimited. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37744071/2700344

Comment: maybe some more insight why the throughput will be limited in ACID mode? my understanding is it's mirco batch to delta file and do compaction periodically. and I see doc mention it even for kafka/flume streaming, could you clarify about throughput a bit. thanks

Comment: Need to test this feature of course more carefully. At read time the reader merges the base and delta files, applying any updates as it reads. So every reader will create additional load. The more readers the more load will be, reducing performance. This will not happen in non-ACID mode. The impact depends on the number of updates. Hive ACID should be used for low concurrency 50 or fewer concurrent users. See here: http://hortonworks.com/blog/apache-hive-acid-transactions-hdp-2-2/ They say that ACID is designed for high throughput, but your readers may consume all available resources.

Answer (score 0):

One Approach could be to use Hive JDBC Connection to perform delete insert or merge in Hive Tables. And then perform full compaction can be executed on Hive ORC table . After Compaction is over data is available through Spark.