# update partitioned hive table if we already have some data in it

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a hive table which is partitioned by day and the data related to 03-02-2017 is loaded into it but, on next day I have data related to 03-03-2017. Now how to update hive table with my new data so that my hive warehouse directory should look like this

```
hive/warehouse/sample_database/sample_table/day=03-02-2017/data_part_0000
hive/warehouse/sample_database/sample_table/day=03-03-2017/data_part_0000
```

So please provide me the code for creating table as well as how to update the table when the new data sets added to this.

Comment: add something you tried

Comment: Please see this solution also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37744071/2700344

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a full demo that describes 2 basic options:

1. Add partitions to the table. The HDFS directories will be created automatically.
2. Add directories to the HDFS and apply **msck repair** on the table to add the partitions.

Note that I'm using the DATE type for the partitions.
The ANSI/ISO notation for date literal is **date 'YYYY-MM-DD'**

Even for older versions that did not support the DATE type I would strongly recommend to avoid any date format other than YYYY-MM-DD, for 2 reasons:
1. This is the only format supported by the date functions.
2. This format allows correct alphabetical comparison, e.g. -
   '2017-01-22' > '2016-09-22' but '01-22-2017' < '09-22-2016'

### Demo

**bash**

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /hive/warehouse/sample_database/sample_table
```

**hive**

```
create external table sample_table
(
    i int
)
partitioned by (day date)
location '/hive/warehouse/sample_database/sample_table'
;
```

#### Option 1 - alter table ... add partition ...

**hive**

```
alter table sample_table add partition (day=date '2017-03-02');
alter table sample_table add partition (day=date '2017-03-03');
```

---

```
hive> show partitions sample_table;
OK
day=2017-03-02
day=2017-03-03
Time taken: 0.067 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
hive> dfs -ls /hive/warehouse/sample_database/sample_table;
Found 2 items
... 2017-03-04 23:31 /hive/warehouse/sample_database/sample_table/day=2017-03-02
... 2017-03-04 23:31 /hive/warehouse/sample_database/sample_table/day=2017-03-03
hive>
```

#### Option 2 - hdfs dfs -mkdir ... + msck repair table ...

**bash**

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir /hive/warehouse/sample_database/sample_table/day=2017-03-02
hdfs dfs -mkdir /hive/warehouse/sample_database/sample_table/day=2017-03-03
```

**hive**

```
msck repair
```

---

```
hive> show partitions sample_table;
OK
Time taken: 0.187 seconds
hive> msck repair table sample_table;
OK
Partitions not in metastore:    sample_table:day=2017-03-02 sample_table:day=2017-03-03
Repair: Added partition to metastore sample_table:day=2017-03-02
Repair: Added partition to metastore sample_table:day=2017-03-03
Time taken: 0.143 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
hive> show partitions sample_table;
OK
day=2017-03-02
day=2017-03-03
Time taken: 0.076 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
hive> dfs -ls /hive/warehouse/sample_database/sample_table;
Found 2 items
... 2017-03-04 23:31 /hive/warehouse/sample_database/sample_table/day=2017-03-02
... 2017-03-04 23:31 /hive/warehouse/sample_database/sample_table/day=2017-03-03
hive>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remember that Hive tables point to somewhere in the HDFS, so that I am not sure what you mean with Hive data warehouse.

For creating the table, you should have to create a partitioned table by day (String), something like:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE myTable
partitioned by (day STRING)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('avro.schema.url'='/path/to/my/avro/schema/avro_schema.avsc')
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
LOCATION '/hive/warehouse/sample_database/sample_table';
```

In the above solution I am assuming you are treating with avro data. The important part actually is: `partitioned by (day STRING)`. Here you are telling Hive that this table will be partitioned by day.

When a new dataset appears in the structure of the directory (`hive/warehouse/sample_database/sample_table/day=03-03-2017/data_part_0000`) and it is not added by an `insert hive statement`, you will have to run this command:

```
msck repair table myTable;
```

This way, a new partition will be added to the metastore of the table. Note that, you have another option:

```
alter table myTable add partition (day = '03-03-2017');
```