# Splitting MERGE statement in Update, Delete and Insert

Tags: oracle, hive, merge-statement

I am trying to migrate one on SQL from Oracle to Hive. To make to work on hive , I have to break Merge statement into UPDATE/DELETE and INSERT.

Please help me on this. I have my version of splitting , but i am not sure on it.

Note: I am not using Hive MERGE for other reason.

**Merge Statement:**

```
MERGE INTO bonuses D
 USING (SELECT employee_id, salary, department_id FROM employees
 WHERE department_id = 80) S
 ON (D.employee_id = S.employee_id)
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET D.bonus = D.bonus + S.salary*.01  WHERE (S.salary > 8000)
   DELETE WHERE (S.salary >= 10000)
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (D.employee_id, D.bonus)
   VALUES (S.employee_id, S.salary*.01)
   WHERE (S.salary <= 8000);
```

**Table DDLs:**

```
CREATE TABLE bonuses (employee_id NUMBER, bonus NUMBER DEFAULT 100);
CREATE TABLE employees ( employee_id NUMBER, salary NUMBER, department_id int);
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Post what you came up with an perhaps people will comment on it. Your question might be better asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.  Thanks.

Comment: is this statement your own case?

Comment: Unfortunately , I can't share original Merge statement .so i have created similar one.

Comment: Use `insert overwrite table with full join`, see example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37744071/2700344  Write your case statements and filters.

Comment: As quoted in Question, I want  simply breaking up  MERGE into individual UPDATE/DELETE/INSERT.   if don't want to use HIVE ACID , then individual UPDATE/DELETE can be converted in insert override.  Hope it clarifies the question.