# HIVE how to update the existing data if it exists based on some condition and insert new data if not exists

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop2

I want to update the existing data if it exists based on some condition(data with higher priority should be updated) and insert new data if not exists.

I have already written a query for this but somehow it is duplicating the number of rows. Here is the full explanation of what I have and what I want to achieve:

What I have:
Table 1 - columns - id,info,priority

```
hive> select * from sample1;
OK
1   123     1.01
2   234     1.02
3   213     1.03
5   213423  1.32
Time taken: 1.217 seconds, Fetched: 4 row(s)
```

Table 2: columns - id,info,priority

```
hive> select * from sample2;
OK
1   1234    1.05
2   23412   1.01
3   21      1.05
4   1232    1.1
2   3432423 1.6
3   34324   1.4
```

What I want is the final table should have only 1 row per id with the data according to the greatest priority:

```
1   1234    1.05
2   3432423 1.6
3   34324   1.4
4   1232    1.1
5   213423  1.32
```

The query that I have written is this:

```
insert overwrite table sample1
select a.id,
case when cast(TRIM(a.prio) as double) > cast(TRIM(b.prio) as double) then a.info else b.info end as info,
case when cast(TRIM(a.prio) as double) > cast(TRIM(b.prio) as double) then a.prio else b.prio end as prio
from sample1 a
join 
sample2 b
on a.id=b.id where b.id in (select distinct(id) from sample1)
union all
select * from sample2 where id not in (select distinct(id) from sample1)
union all
select * from sample1 where id not in (select distinct(id) from sample2);
```

After running this query, I am getting this result:

```
hive> select * from sample1;
OK
1   1234    1.05
2   234     1.02
3   21      1.05
2   3432423 1.6
3   34324   1.4
5   213423  1.32
4   1232    1.1
```

How do I modify the present query to achieve the correct result. Is there any other method/process that I can follow to achieve the end result. I am using hadoop 2.5.2 along with HIVE 1.2.1 . I am working on a 6 node cluster with 5 slaves and 1 NN.

Comment: because p_gender holds a double value but the datatype is string which we need to compare with a double value so we needed to cast it as a string to hold the comparison.

Comment: Please see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Use `FULL JOIN`, it will return all joined rows plus all not joined rows from the left and all not joined rows from the right tables. 
`sample2` table contains duplicated rows per `id`, this is why join duplicates rows, use `row_number()` analytic function to select only rows with highest priority from `sample2` table:

```
insert overwrite table sample1
select 
      nvl(a.id, b.id) as id,
      case when cast(TRIM(a.prio) as double) > cast(TRIM(b.prio) as double) then a.info else b.info end as info,
      case when cast(TRIM(a.prio) as double) > cast(TRIM(b.prio) as double) then a.prio else b.prio end as prio
from ( select a.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by prio desc) rn 
         from sample1 a
     ) a
     full join 
          ( select b.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by prio desc) rn
              from sample2 b
          ) b on a.id=b.id and b.rn=1 --join only with highest priority rows
where a.rn=1;
```

If `sample1` table also contains multiple rows per `id` (it is not in your example), apply the same technique using row_number to the table sample1.

See also the answer about merge using `full join`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37744071/2700344

Also as of Hive 2.2 you can use ACID Merge, see [examples](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/97113/hive-acid-merge-by-example.html)

Comment: Thank you. I will test this and let you know.

Comment: I have updated my question with a more accurate situation that I am facing currently. Any help would be appreciated. I sincerely thank you for your support till now.

Comment: Sir, I am getting multiple rows even after applying row_number function as mentioned by you above. you can check the output here : https://pastebin.com/vy9hjPjq

Comment: And initial data is the same as you have posted?

Comment: What if I truncate sample 1 and insert everything from scratch using sample 2 ? I have multiple priority attributes for a single row of data and each priority attribute is responsible for 4 different attributes. I need to update these 4 attributes per priority value for each ID.

Comment: @RishabhDixit added filtering by rn for the first table

Comment: This is the output after the modified query : https://pastebin.com/rqHPAyFJ . After this I also removed all the data from sample1, and executed the query. After the query execution, sample1 remained empty.

Answer (score 0):

Since I had multiple id rows for each id, so I firstly consolidated the IDs using a spark script. The solution could be found here : [SPARK 2.2.2 - Joining multiple RDDs giving out of memory excepton. Resulting RDD has 124 columns. What should be the optimal joining method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53120335/spark-2-2-2-joining-multiple-rdds-giving-out-of-memory-excepton-resulting-rdd)
Then I used the query mentioned in the question to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

adding to previously good answers!
try this also:

```
insert overwrite table UDB.SAMPLE1
select 
 COALESCE(id2,id )
,COALESCE(info2,info)
,COALESCE(priority2, priority)
from 
UDB.SAMPLE1 TAB1
full outer JOIN
(
select id2, info2, priority2
from
(
select 
 id       as id2
,info     as info2
,priority as priority2
,row_number() over (partition by id order by priority desc) rn
from UDB.SAMPLE2
)TAB2_wt
where TAB2_wt.rn =1
)TAB2
on TAB2.id2 = TAB1.id
;

select * from SAMPLE1;

+-----+----------+-----------+--+
| id  |   info   | priority  |
+-----+----------+-----------+--+
| 1   | 1234     | 1.05      |
| 2   | 3432423  | 1.6       |
| 3   | 34324    | 1.4       |
| 4   | 1232     | 1.1       |
| 5   | 213423   | 1.32      |
+-----+----------+-----------+--+
```

Comment: Your solution seems good for this data but for multiple priority and ID columns, I doubt that this will work. Please take sample data from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53120335/spark-2-2-2-joining-multiple-rdds-giving-out-of-memory-excepton-resulting-rdd). I doubt that we can do this without using window functions.