# Can we perform crud operation on "text file" in hive

Tags: hive, bigdata, hiveql, cloudera, hortonworks-sandbox

I am a newbie to Hadoop, before posting this question I have already searched on google and found all the crud operations example with only ORC files. So wanted to know if we can do the same with a text file or any changes are required in syntax.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Typical Templates for CRUD operations in non-ACID mode:**

**C:** insert is the same (can be from select)

```
INSERT INTO TABLE table_name VALUES... or SELECT FROM ...
```

**R:** this is simple

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE table_name WHERE ...
```

**U:** Owerwrite the whole table or partition using **select from itself** (use joins to update with values from other table). Update columns using CASE statements.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE table_name [PARTITION(key=value)] 
SELECT --update columns using CASE
       case when col=some_value then some_other_value end as col,
       ...
       case when coln=some_value then some_other_value end as coln,
       col_x --not updated column
  FROM table_name [WHERE partition_key=value]
       JOIN...
```

**D:** This is the whole table or partition rewrite using **select from itself with filter**. Can be combined with update.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE table_name [PARTITION(key=value)] 
SELECT *
  FROM table_name [WHERE partition_key=value]
WHERE --Filter out records you want to delete
```

Also please read this answer about [**MERGE**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37744071/2700344).

See the manual on [**Hive DML**](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML).