# HIVE Query: How to select the 'join key' for "FULL OUTER JOIN"?

Tags: sql, join, hive, hiveql

I got the following error:

```
Multiple attributes named business_id in reportAttributeReferenceAmbiguous; p.business_id, s.business_id
```

from the SPARK/HIVE query:

```
SELECT
    business_id,
    p.p1,
    p.p2,
    s.s1,
    s.s2
FROM p_table p
FULL OUTER JOIN s_table s
    ON p.business_id = s.business_id
```

Since I am using `FULL OUTER JOIN`, `business_id` could be either `p.business_id` or `s.business_id`, so I didn't specify which one to use. (I thought some rows might have only `p.business_id` while some other rows might have only `s.business_id`, do I understand this wrong?)

So I am wondering what's the proper way to select `business_id` in the above query? Thanks!

Comment: result of join includes all columns from both tables

Comment: you might wanna use COALESCE(p.business_id, s.business_id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
coalesce(p.business_id, s.business_id) as business_id
```

Or

```
nvl(p.business_id, s.business_id) as business_id
```

Or CASE statements like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37744071/2700344

Answer (score 0):

you have `business_id` in both table in your query you select business_id and didn't mention from which table.

```
SELECT
    business_id,
    p.p1,
    p.p2,
    s.s1,
    s.s2
FROM p_table p
FULL OUTER JOIN s_table s
    ON p.business_id = s.business_id
```

above query should change to

```
SELECT
    p.business_id AS pBI, s.business_id AS sBI,
    p.p1,
    p.p2,
    s.s1,
    s.s2
FROM p_table p
FULL OUTER JOIN s_table s
    ON p.business_id = s.business_id
```

I didn't check but you can try .