# How to handle a incremental data in Hive when the time of receiving data suddenly changes

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am new in Hive..
I get data on first of every month. This data is stored as
partitioned table in Hive. Suppose I get data in the middle of the month[any date],then do I delete the old partition and create a new partition with the latest date..

Please suggest me a solution..

Comment: What is your current partition key ? You can partition by `month` and delete data for that month and reload it.

Comment: We can make our own decision on the partition key .Do we have to delete the old partition or some alternative is there?

Comment: Partitioning scheme is not necessarily related to how you load data. And data increment may contain updates and new data for existing partition with old data. All depends on your scenario and design

Comment: We have to make the best decision..

Comment: Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37744071/2700344